# Nodejs elasticsearch client helper bulk update

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

I have data like this in my es index:

```
{
  "_index": "pelias",
  "_type": "_doc",
  "_id": "openaddresses:venue:59a09004887bce7373e117163e5761f1",
  "_version": 5,
  "_score": 0,
  "_source": {
    "center_point": {
      "lon": 106.633333,
      "lat": 10.828199
    },
    "parent": {
      "region": [
        "Thành phố Hồ Chí Minh"
      ],
      "region_id": [
        "79"
      ],
      "region_a": [
        "TPHCM"
      ],
      "county": [
        "Quận Tân Bình"
      ],
      "county_id": [
        "79766"
      ],
      "county_a": [
        "QTB"
      ],
      "locality": [
        "Phường 15"
      ],
      "locality_id": [
        "7976627007"
      ],
      "locality_a": [
        "P15"
      ]
    },
    "popularity": 1634576400,
    "name": {
      "default": "C28 Đường Phan Huy Ích, Phường 15, Tân Bình, Hồ Chí Minh, Việt Nam"
    },
    "source": "openaddresses",
    "source_id": "59a09004887bce7373e117163e5761f1",
    "layer": "venue"
  }
}
```

Now I want to update the **center_point**. I tried to use the helper but it keep return failed without error mesasage. Here is my code:

```
const result = await client.helpers.bulk({
      datasource: updatePayload,
      onDocument(doc) {
        return [
          { update: { _index: "pelias", _id: doc["_id"] } },
          { doc_as_upsert: false },
        ];
      },
    });

console.log(result);
```

The updatePayload variable used to update:

```
[ { center_point: { lat: 10.77711802, lon: 106.6937548 },
    _id: 'wrong_location:address:faf87656ec9ba08d39b331b5af41e645' },
  { center_point: { lat: 10.78375092, lon: 106.6506849 },
    _id: 'wrong_location:address:724f94ada8606c0e8afe0e28c7e82081' }]
```

Any help is really appreciated. Many thanks.

Node ver: 16.13.1

@elastic/elasticsearch: 7.15.0

Answer (score 0):

You're not sending the center point data, try this instead:

```
const result = await client.helpers.bulk({
  datasource: updatePayload,
  onDocument(doc) {
    return [
      { update: { _index: "pelias", _id: doc["_id"] } },
      { doc_as_upsert: false, "doc": { center_point: doc["center_point"] } },
    ];
  },
});

console.log(result);
```